# Change Openstreetmaps LayerSwitcher Position

Tags: position, layer, openstreetmap

Is there a native function to set the LayerSwitcher position to the top right Corner?

I tried to do this with css:

```
.olControlLayerSwitcher{
float: right;
position: relative;
}
```

While doing this firebug shows property position: relative als struck through?

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```css
.olControlLayerSwitcher .maximizeDiv, .olControlLayerSwitcher .minimizeDiv {
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0px;
    top: 25px;
}
```